# Why my opencart products images show blurry? how to fix?

Tags: image, opencart, blurry

I am using journal opencart theme. when i upload a product then my products images showing blurry. please guide me how can i fix this?
my website link is:
accity.ru

please help me to fix this

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question in the first place, so it might be inappropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud check if:

- you are uploading images in proper resolution
- you have properly set image sizes in opencart administration [system->settings->your eshop->images]
- in your image zooming plugin is not anny setting that can reduce image quality

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on checking the following :

1. All images should be of the same sizes ( & if possible greater than 500x500 )
2. The resizing if needed should maintain the aspect ratio 

   Example: 1200x800 can be resized to 600x400, 300x200, 150x100 size images easily

Since you are operating an e-commerce store, I suggest, you can also look for professional services such as [ImageKit](https://imagekit.io/blog/) to add capabilities of dynamic resizing, watermarking & many more.

In case issue still persists, feel free to connect with me.